# How can I get in VBA multiple values of a list field on my Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

For a Excel inquiry tool I need to get all selected values from a multiple-select list field I pasted from "Developer Tools > Insert > Form control elements" which is on my Excel sheet (not a User Form).

[image: My list field]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this VBA approach to store all values selected in string (you can adjust code to your needs). In order to execute code, you need ether assign it to listbox macro, or some other shape in your worksheet.

```
Sub ListBoxSelected()
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet.ListBoxes("List Box 1")
        For i = 1 To .ListCount
            If .Selected(i) Then
                allselected = Range("A" & i).Value & ", " & allselected
            End If
        Next i
        MsgBox "Selected: " & allselected 'you can adjust this part to do what you want with selected values
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to test this solution, but ListBoxes() is not definded. I use Excel 2010.

Comment: Make sure your listbox is named `"List Box 1"`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this link.

http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut18.htm

I think you need to do something like this . . .

```
For Each varItem In Me.lstOffice.ItemsSelected
    strOffice = strOffice & ",'" & Me.lstOffice.ItemData(varItem) _
    & "'"
Next varItem
```

If the list box contains a list of dates:

```
For Each varItem In Me.lstBirthDate.ItemsSelected
    strBirthDate = strBirthdate & ",#" &
    Me.lstBirthDate.ItemData(varItem) & "#"
Next varItem
```

Note that the single quotes have been replaces by hash marks (marked in red). The resulting IN() clause looking something like this:

WHERE tblStaff.[BirthDate] IN(#9/27/1950#,#2/7/1968#,#6/19/1977#)

If the list box contains a list of numbers:

```
For Each varItem In Me.lstID.ItemsSelected
    strID = strID & "," & Me.lstID.ItemData(varItem)
Next varItem
```